# GGsurvplot shows wrong percentages in risktable

Tags: r, survival

I used `ggsurvplot` to draw failure(with fun = "event" argument) probabilites at different time points. The % numbers in the Risktable are not correct. Do you know why? Is it possible to change that manually that is change the column  pct.risk
in the data.survtable dataframe ?

```
  f0 <- survfit(Surv(data$period1, event) ~ 1, 
             weights=frequency, conf.type="plain", 
             conf.int=0.9, data = data)
        
 t <- ggsurvplot(f0, data = data, ylab = " ", risk.table = 
                   "abs_pct" ,xlim = c(0,135),
                   break.x.by = 27, fun = "event" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the frequencies and percentages in the table are being scaled up in the `ggsurvplot()` call, when the `weights = frequency` argument is used in the call to `survfit()`. This also happens when you plot a survival curve, rather than the event curve as you have plotted.

This is a bug and should be reported to the survminer authors/github. Here's a reproducible example, using the lung cancer dataset from the `survival::` package.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
data(lung)

f0 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(f0, ylab = " ", risk.table = "abs_pct", fun = "event" ) 
# This gives the resulting plot, which looks fine.
```

[image: Unweighted figure]

---

```
# Now tweak the example code to make each line represent ten people:
lung2 <- lung
lung2$freq <- 10

f1 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, weights=freq, data = lung2)
ggsurvplot(f1, risk.table = "abs_pct", fun = "event" ) 

# Resulting plot... due to the first n isn't fully printed but is n=2280 (228 x 10) 
# but I didn't want to clutter the code by tweaking the font size.
```

[image: Event plot weighted by factor of ten]

This quite clearly indicates that not only are the frequencies being scaled in the table by the factor of ten (good!) but so are the percentages (not good!).

Comment: Just adding a note that I filed this on GitHub. https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/561. You can see some potential fixes to the underlying code.